# Manipular Valores Decimais em EXCEL + VB

Tags: java, microsoft-excel, visual-studio

Tenho uma aplicação que disponibiliza um webservice(ws) (java) mas preciso transportar dados para uma folha excel e imprimir, o meu problema é o seguinte, quando obtenho os valores do ws dependendo do reginal setting do sistema operativo, obtenho em formatos diferentes Ex: 90.01 ou 9001, quando ele nao traz o ponto ele lê como um numero inteiro e eu preciso de ter ele como decimal. Mudar o egional setting nao é uma solução valida pois não posso obrigar o utilizador a isso, por isso procuro uma forma de obter o valor correcto (90.01)com o VB.

Alguem ai tem alguma solução ou dica que ajude?

Comment: Você não poderia converter os dados em inteiro antes de transporta-los para o Excel e criar uma rotina no Excel tratar isso?

Comment: Não da pois há outra aplicacao que usa o webservice e esta ok, e alem disso preciso das casa decimais.